# iOS Get past Login form.

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios5, uiwebview

I have the following code for my application.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Set the values
    NSString* firstValue = @"guest";
    NSString* secondValue = @"guest";
    // write javascript code in a string
    NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value=%@;"
    "document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value=%@;"
    "document.forms['form1'].submit();";

    // insert string values into javascript
    javaScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat: javaScriptString, firstValue, secondValue];

    // run javascript in webview:
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScriptString];
}

- (void)launchWebPageWithOptions
{    
    NSString *urlString = @"http://demo.leadtools.com/MedicalViewer/default.aspx";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [iOSWebView loadRequest:requestObject];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self launchWebPageWithOptions];
}
```

For some reason, I am unable to execute the automatic login using the javascript calls. I am no JS Expert so if you can see any error in my javaScriptString, PLEASE let me know,

Comment: Are the `"` at the beginning and end of the lines part of the JS or part of the Obj-C?

Comment: objective-c. the inside of the @"" is the JavaScript

Comment: Did you run the JS through JSHint?

Comment: Careful! You're posting live credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your user and password formatted values to be quoted:

```
NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value='%@';"
    "document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value='%@';"
    "document.forms['form1'].submit();";
```

Notice that I've changed `value=%@` to `value='%@'` in both cases. This will properly fill-in the input boxes.

Next, call the `click()` function on the Login button rather than calling `submit()` on the form:

```
NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value='%@';"
    "document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value='%@';"
    "document.getElementById('Login1_LoginButton').click()";
```

this will allow the `onclick` javascript specified for the Login button to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the string quotes.

Try this:

```
NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value='%@';"
"document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value='%@';"
"document.forms['form1'].submit();";
```